# How to efficiently wait for CTS or DSR of RS232 in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port, wait

Currently, I'm reading the CTS and DSR signals of a serial port in the following way:

```
bool get_cts(int fd) {
    int s;
    ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &s);
    return (s & TIOCM_CTS) != 0;
}
```

Now I'd like to wait until `get_cts()` returns true. A simple loop isn't the best solution I think (as it's extremely resource-intensive).

```
void wait_cts(int fd) {
    while(1) {
        if(get_cts(fd)) {
             return;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution using C or C++ on Linux? (I cannot use any hardware flow control as I don't need the serial data lines at all.)

Comment: Any reason why you can't sleep a bit in that loop?

Comment: I could do that but is there no other solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the ioctl `TIOCMIWAIT` which blocks until a given set of signals change.

Sadly this ioctl is not documented in the `tty_ioctl(4)` page nor in `ioctl_list(4)`.

I have learned about this ioctl in this question:

[Python monitor serial port (RS-232) handshake signals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5904895/947357)

Comment: It is now in tty_ioctl(2) on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The select system call is meant for applications like that. You can do other work, or sleep, then periodically check the status of the FD_SET.  It might even be overkill for what you are doing, if your program does nothing else but grab data.