# Making a serial port notify on change of handshaking lines

Tags: linux, serial-port

Is it possible to open a serial device (such as `/dev/ttyS0`) and be informed via `select`/`poll`/etc... or a signal when the handshaking lines (such as `CTS`/`RTS` or `DSR`/`DTR`) change? I know at the hardware level there's an interrupt from the UART to tell the kernel it has changed, but can I be informed of that up in userland?

---

*Edit*: I am aware of `TIOCMIWAIT`, but that `ioctl` call blocks until the status lines change. I would like instead to keep processing generally and have a `poll` or similar be informed on change, as well as other events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to efficiently wait for CTS or DSR of RS232 in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952098/how-to-efficiently-wait-for-cts-or-dsr-of-rs232-in-linux)

Comment: Not directly - that post only talks about `TIOCMIWAIT`, which blocks until the status bits change. I'd like to be informed asynchronously, either by select/poll wakeup, or a signal.

Comment: OK, good point.  Now how do I unflag? I guess I can upvote to compensate ;-)

Comment: Can you do what you want by having the `ioctl TIOCMIWAIT` in a separate thread?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to wait for the DTR/RTS lines to change in userland.  The only way to do this on Linux is to constantly poll the device, checking to see if the status of the RTS/DTR lines have changed.  I generally steal my serial port code from gtkerm, and [it polls](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/gtkterm.git/tree/src/serie.c?id=c62d7ce8ec7c77dfc3a61a4434da2499ef4e1fc0#n366).

You can try using `TIOCMIWAIT`, but if I remember correctly that's going to be very tied to the driver for the serial port that Linux is using, and so may not work from driver to driver.